# error of drawing map from shape file in Python 3.2 basemap

Tags: python, python-3.x, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I am working on drawing map from shape file in Python 3.2 basemap.

But, the longitude values at the bottom axis are only shown partially. 
Also, all latitude values are missing.

Here is my python code.

```
import shapefile as sf
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

 map = Basemap(projection='stere', lon_0=-106.4, lat_0= 31.9, lat_ts  = 31.9, \
               llcrnrlat=31.7, urcrnrlat= 31.85, \
               llcrnrlon=-106.5 , urcrnrlon= -106.1, \
               rsphere=6371200., resolution='l', area_thresh=1000)

 plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(10, 8), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

parallels = np.arange(31.7, 31.85, 0.25)

map.drawparallels(parallels, labels=[0, 0, 0, 1] , fontsize=10, labelstyle='+/-', dashes=[2, 2])

meridians = np.arange (-106.5, -106.1, 0.25)

map.drawmeridians(meridians, labels=[0, 0, 0, 1], fontsize=10, labelstyle='+/-' , dashes=[2, 2])
```

No matter how I changed the labels, the latitude/longitude legend values are still missing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess answer to the question is already irrelevant, but may be useful to someone else. You need to change the lines in the code

```
parallels = np.arange(31.7, 31.85, 0.25)
map.drawparallels(parallels, labels=[0, 0, 0, 1],...)
```

on

```
parallels = np.arange(31.7, 31.85, 0.025)
map.drawparallels(parallels, labels=[1, 1, 0, 0],...)
```

or shorter

```
map.drawparallels(np.arange(31.7, 31.85, 0.025), labels=[1, 1, 0, 0],...)
```

Your latitude values were missed because they are not included in interval 31.7-31.85 (31.7+0.25=31.95, and 31.95 > 31.85)